# postgresql db functions are not working

Tags: php, function, postgresql, postgis

I was trying to get the nearest people from mover_location table using the query as follows :

```
select * from mover_location where
public.st_dwithin(public.st_geogfromtext('SRID=4326;POINT(11.2565999 75.7711587)'),
last_seen_location_geog, 1060)
```

Which is not working and give me error like as follows :

```
ERROR:  function _st_expand(public.geography, double precision) does not exist
```

and i didnt called the st_expand function , How can i resolve this ,Or is there any other

workarounds ?  thanks .

My mover_location table structure is as follows ,here last_seen_location_geog is of geography type

[image]

**UPDATE :-**

```
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT $1 && _ST_Expand($2,$3) AND $2 && _ST_Expand($1,$3) AND _ST_DWithin($1, $2, $3, true)
CONTEXT:  SQL function "st_dwithin" during inlining
```

Comment: What version of Postgis are you using? This is relevant because there are various forms of the ST_DWithin function, that were introduced in different version, not all of which support geography datatype and one of which uses ST_Expand internally.

Comment: How did you install PostGIS?

Comment: I installed the Enterprise db full packeage including pgadminIII , postgis and stackbuilder , I dont know the exact version of postgis , but its installed as postgresql version 9.3

Comment: It is PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export Manager 2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Add public schema to your search_path:

`set search_path to your_schema, public;`

Comment: okay it was resolved earlier , the problem was not installed the postgis extension